# Call steps from within json data - Bootstro

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstro

Is it possible to call steps to order the 'tour' from within json data e.g.

```
"selector":"#profilePic",
"title":"Ajaxed Title 2",
"content":"I was found because I have selector=#demo_ajax",
"width":"400px",
"placement":"bottom",
"step":"2"
```

I know it can be done by injecting html into the divs but I'd rather not pollute with code which may be used once or twice in a users lifetime on the site

Answer (score 0):

For some reason they don't have this in the documentation, but the source code for the docs page shows how it works:

`bootstro.start('', {url : './bootstro.json'});`